# error al hacer clave secundaria en mysql

Tags: mysql

Me cree una base de datos en freesqldatabase, hice una tabla "cuentas" con una clave primaria en la columna "id".

Ahora hice una tabla "datospaciente" con una columna "idrelacionada" que es clave primaria, y esta la intento poner como clave foranea, relacionando el idrelacionada con el id de cuentas, lo he puesto así:

```sql
ALTER TABLE sql11509403.datospaciente ADD CONSTRAINT datospaciente_FK FOREIGN KEY (idrelacionado) REFERENCES sql11509403.cuentas(id);
```

Pero me da error:

> Can't create table 'sql11509403.#sql-3115_4270a4e' (errno: 150)

Lo estoy haciendo con dbeaver.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato y longitud tienen sql11509403.idrelacionado e id que está en datospaciente?

Comment: "con una columna "idrelacionada" que es clave primaria" porque es clave primaria si es foranea a otra tabla?

Comment: ambos tienen el mismo tipo de dato y longitud, 

no puede ser clave primaria de su tabla y a la vez foranea de otra tabla?

Comment: Muestra la esctructura de las tablas implicadas, la puedes obtener ejecutando `SHOW CREATE TABLE datospaciente;` y `SHOW CREATE TABLE cuentas;`

Comment: @ebsigma Si la clave es dependiente entonces no es primaria.

Comment: entonces en la tabla datospaciente, el idrelacionado quiero que sea el mismo del id de la cuenta, por lo que idrelacionado es clave dependiente y no puede ser primaria, entonces la clave primaria en esa tabla no tiene por que existir, si no voy a relacionar ese campo con otra tabla no?

Comment: Las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. Quienes hacen los comentarios verán la pregunta editada. La forma ideal de responder a lo que preguntan es editando la pregunta y mostrando la estructura de las tablas, tla y como te indican